# Mobile facebook about page link requiring fb login

Tags: mobile, facebook-page

I'm trying to get a link to my app to work on mobile devices similar to this:

http://m.facebook.com/angrybirds?id=314467614927

however my mobile web link from the app center requires a facebook login, where the angry birds link does not. Any ideas how to replicate the functionality?

my link:
http://m.facebook.com/appcenter/ansibletestapp

edit:
also filed a bug report with facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/343512979067831

Comment: this question is not off topic if you're developing a facebook app for mobile web. Perhaps it's more appropriate on the facebook stackoverflow, instead of closing it as off topic you could have moved it there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://m.facebook.com/angrybirds?id=314467614927 is the link to the page of the Angry Birds. (Web version here: http://www.facebook.com/angrybirds)

Using an application on facebook will always require authentication, that is a valid session, so the user will have to log in to facebook to view the application.

Comment: are you saying I need to make a landing page for my app that isn't the app center detail page? Do you know what type of page that angrybirds page is?

Comment: The facebook page and facebook application are all different things. A page on facebook is some area on facebook given to you to promote your product/company. Read for more details: https://www.facebook.com/pages

Where as, application is when you want user activity, like if you're building a game.

You can make a page for your application as well, and post a link to the application in the "about" description of the page. Just like angrybirds does.

Comment: More information, found on stackoverflow itself. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-page/info

Comment: are you saying that if I create a fb page, keeping in mind mobile is my target audience, that I can link to it without the page requiring a login?

Comment: Didn't completely answer my question, but i'd rather not let the bounty go to waste so I'll pick this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It's probably related to list of `permissions` listed on **Settings -> Permissions** page for your application. (See [Authorization section of App Center guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#authorization)).

> **Configuring Permissions**
>   Use these settings to enter the set of permissions your app requires when displayed in [App Center](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#authorization) or using [Auth Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals)
>   [Learn more about Configuring Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals)

Listing some of `permissions` in that section of application settings will result in Auth Dialog appearance prior to application visiting from any link on Facebook.

Comment: I disabled auth referalls and removed all permissions from the settings->permissions page. FB still asks users to login before they can see the page: http://m.facebook.com/appcenter/ansibletestapp

Comment: @Ericson578, I can visit your page without any prompt for permissions

Comment: can you visit it from mobile safari on an iphone without being logged into facebook? That was the question

Comment: @Ericson578, in the first place you cannot visit App Center without being logged-in... Angry Birds have a regular Facebook page which doesn't require to log-in. I was describing the behavior for getting into application from App Center (looks like it wasn't what you wanted)...